# Passing a callback to a component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, beginner, ecmascript-6, to-do-list, vue.js

I'm currently trying to teach myself Vue.js and I've just created my first small project: a simple todo list. While writing the component I discovered that you can't access methods from the parent component directly, but I didn't want to put one half of the code in the child component (the `deleteToDo` method), so I've passed a callback to it. Is this okay in Vue or is there any other preferred way of structuring things like this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q6vznfa/)

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: ['todo', 'delete_callback'],
    template: `<li>
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.done">
                    <input v-model="todo.text" :disabled="todo.done" @change="todoChanged(todo)">
                    <a @click="delete_callback(todo)">X</a>
                </li>`,
    methods: {
        todoChanged: function (todo) {
            if (this.todo.text == '') {
                this.delete_callback(todo);
            }
        }
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        show: {
            todo: true,
            done: false
        },
        todos: [
            {
                id: 0,
                text: 'Test this stuff',
                done: true
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'Learn more Vue',
                done: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                text: 'Buy some tasty food',
                done: false
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addTodo: function (event) {
            if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent && event.key != 'Enter') {
                return;
            }
            if (event.target.value != '') {
                this.todos.push({
                    id: this.todos.length,
                    text: event.target.value,
                    done: false
                });
                event.target.value = '';
            }
        },
        deleteToDo: function (todo) {
            this.todos.splice(todo.id, 1);
            for (let i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
                this.todos[i].id = i;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font: 16px "Helvetica Neue", status-bar;
    background-color: #444444;
}

#app {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 3rem auto;
    padding: 1rem 3rem 3rem 3rem;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    color: #444444;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

li > input:disabled {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

li > a, h4 > span {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

li > a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #222222;
}

#newtodo {
    margin-left: 23px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ToDo</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>ToDo List</h1>
            <h4 @click="show.todo = !show.todo">To Do: {{ todos.filter(todo => !todo.done).length }} <span>({{ show.todo ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }})</span></h4>
            <ul v-show="show.todo">
                <todo-item v-for="todo in todos" v-if="!todo.done" :todo="todo" :key="todo.id" :delete_callback="deleteToDo"></todo-item>
                <input id="newtodo" type="text" placeholder="New todo item" @keypress="addTodo" @blur="addTodo"></input>
            </ul>
            <h4 @click="show.done = !show.done">Done: {{ todos.filter(todo => todo.done).length }} <span>({{ show.done ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }})</span></h4>
            <ul v-show="show.done">
                <todo-item v-for="todo in todos" v-if="todo.done" :todo="todo" :key="todo.id" :delete_callback="deleteToDo"></todo-item>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ! I didn't know about this feature yet. I've included both the HTML and CSS snippets as well now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your question

> so I've passed a callback to it. Is this okay in Vue or is there any other preferred way of structuring things like this?

If you haven't already, I would suggest you read the VueJS [documentation for **Components**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) - specifically the section [*Listening to Child Components Events*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events). Basically the child component can utilize the built-in [`$emit` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) to emit an event, which can be handled by the parent using `v-on`.

BTW the last section of the [Documentation page **List rendering**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) has a section [*`v-for` with a Component*](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-a-component) that includes a simple TODO list using `$emit`.

---

#### Other feedback

You might want to consider using a *key* that is the index of each item - see the second example of [Mapping an Array to Elements with `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) of the documentation:

```
<todo-item v-for="(todo, index) in todos" v-if="todo.done" :todo="todo" :key="index"
```

That way you don't have to re-assign the id values when deleting an item.

---

The Vue object is assigned to a variable `vm`

```
var vm = new Vue({
```

but it is never used after that. According to [ESLint](https://eslint.org): "*Such variables take up space in the code and can lead to confusion by readers.*"<sup>[1](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)</sup>.

---

The text input element for the new item has a separate closing tag:

> ```
> <input id="newtodo" type="text" placeholder="New todo item" @keypress="addTodo" @blur="addTodo"></input>
> ```

But input elements have no permitted content<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)</sup> <sup>[3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element)</sup> and thus are [empty elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element).

> *In HTML, using a closing tag on an empty element is usually invalid. For example, `<input type="text"></input>` is invalid HTML.*<sup>[4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element)</sup>

The jsFiddle syntax highlighting also points this out (I added some colored boxes to point this out):

[image: jsFiddle syntax highlighting]

Because of this, the closing slash can be added to the end of the start tag:

```
<input id="newtodo" type="text" placeholder="New todo item" @keypress="addTodo" @blur="addTodo" />
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element</sub>

<sup>4</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great answer :)

Comment: @SamOnela I'm seeing the mentioned vue todo https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html but it appears there is not method defined that removes a todo item...

Comment: @RobertRocha - that is true - notice that the remove button is coded as `<button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">Remove</button>` so when it is clicked it doesn't call a method on the todo-item component but rather emits an event to the parent. Note that the parent element has `v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)"` on the `<li is="todo-item"` element so it doesn't need a method but one could certainly call a method in either place if it was necessary.